# How to set values to pojo class from Java Hashmap

Tags: java, spring, pojo, dto

I have created a below code which will read excel sheet and store the data into hashmap.

```
   public static void getValue()
    {
      Map<Integer, List<String>> getValues= new HashMap<Integer,List<String>>();
      String fileLocation = ".//clone1//Sample.xls";
      File f = new File(fileLocation);
      FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
      Workbook book = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
      Sheet sheet = book.getSheetAt(0);

        for (int i = 1; i <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) 
        {
                Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
                List<String> datai = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int j = 0; j < row.getLastCellNum(); j++) 
              {
                row.getCell(j, Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);

                datai.add(row.getCell(j).getStringCellValue());
              }
                    getValues.put(i,datai);

        }
    }
```

OUTPUT of the HashMap some think like below:

Key :0
Values:["mercury","Mercury"]

Key:1
Values:["Amazon","Kindle"]

And "key" represent rows count in excel sheet and "Values" represent the username, and password columns which is stored in List in Map.

As per output the excel sheet has two active rows, and 4 active cell values.

*+Sample POJO Class+*

```
   public class DataSet
    {
     private username;
     private password;

     //getter and setters methods for username, and password
    }
```

I would like to apply the values to pojo class. and which is the efficient way to achieve set the pojo object values from Map.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it using stream in one sort:

```
List<DataSet> data = getValues.values().stream()
                .filter(l -> l.getSize() >= 2)
                .map(l -> new DataSet(l.get(0), l.get(1)))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: It really helps. but I haven't start using java8. can you pls give me an idea in java7. Also is there any way to get the values without using index based, and add objects to list<DataSet>.

Comment: YOu have a list. You must access item in list by index. You can use foreach loop to avoid index, but it's ugly

Comment: many thanks for your response. let me get any idea if the list has few more values, and some times can be empty too. I tried to get from index whenever I had empty cell and Its considered as blank and all the values are mismatching if i start using index.

Comment: Then you want to change your initial data structure to `Map<Integer, Map<String, String>>`. Its look like: `{0 -> {userName: A, passWord: B}}`. The you can avoid the index, just look for the name of value.

Comment: No not like that. let it be a List<String> which holds all the cell in 0 row.

Comment: You change your initial datastructure to my suggested one (`Map<Integer, Map<String, String>>`), then you can achieve what you want.

Comment: Let me give a try.